A word combining 'menacing' and 'trashy'
I'm doing some proofreading and suggestions for a friend who's writing a book. In it, a rather vanilla middle-class white male American sees a Gothy punk woman (I'm butchering his description) with a full arm sleeve. Neither of us can think of a good word or short phrase for how the man would describe the tattoo that combines 'looking dangerous/aggressive/menacing' and 'looking low-class.' The character in question spent some time in prison, so the word doesn't need to be derogatory.
We've been scouring various online thesauruses and everything we come across that sounds even remotely close either seems like something from the 1800s or something you'd hear while wandering a country club with 100k a year membership fee (or both!).

Welcome to EL&U! What have you come across, that you don't need repeating?

You could replace one of the adjectives in your question with a different adjective and ask if there's a word that encapsulates the meanings of those two adjectives. Surely, you can't find such a word all the time (as in this case.) What's the problem with using two adjectives?

Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence that conveys the context in which it will be used. Could you do that?

If you describe something or someone as sleazy, you disapprove of them because you think they are not respectable and are rather disgusting or because it looks dirty and badly cared for.  (Collins)

Can you provide a source where a tattoo is described as typical of upper-class sophistication?

How about feral?

Why can't the man think whatever he thinks if he's fictional? Menacing, sexy, fearful, erotic, low-class, subversive, brave? Dark, alien, artistic, Goth, Punk, slutty, seductive?

I suggest the simple word mean which has a lot of nuance.

The woman had a mean tattoo.

Cambridge Dictionary has for the adjective mean:

unkind or unpleasant:
Stop being so mean to me!
frightening and likely to become violent:
a mean-looking youth
very good:
She plays a mean piano.
poor, dirty, and of bad quality:
He was living in a mean little hut.

Also Mean Street and Mean Streets are the title of various books, movies, and songs and are typically about places that are difficult or challenging to survive.
